# Object Reference Not Set to an Instance of an Object at Repository Layer

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern, nullreferenceexception, unit-of-work

I am receiving null exception error on my framework. I have tried to apply Repository and Unit of Work design patterns in my application. What I am trying to do is simply retreiving user titles from my data base with `GetAll()` method.

Here is my repository class:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    protected readonly DbContext Context;

    public Repository(DbContext context)
    {
        this.Context = context;
    }

    public T Get(int id)
    {
        return Context.Set<T>().Find(id);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return Context.Set<T>().ToList();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return Context.Set<T>().Where(predicate);
    }

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        Context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
    }

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> entityList)
    {
        Context.Set<T>().AddRange(entityList);
    }

    public void Remove(T entity)
    {
        Context.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
    }

    public void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<T> entityList)
    {
        Context.Set<T>().RemoveRange(entityList);
    }
}
```

This is `IUserTitlesRepository`:

```
public interface IUserTitlesRepository : IRepository<UserTitles>
{

}
```

And, the class where above interface implemented:

```
    public UserTitlesRepository(XaPaDataContext context) : base(context)
    {

    }

    public XaPaDataContext XaPaDataContext
    {
        get { return Context as XaPaDataContext; }
    }
```

Before coming to Controller layer, I have two more layers, which are Operation and Manager layers. And, I think I have messed up on that part (on Base Manager class as shown below).

This is operation layer:

```
public class UserTitlesOperations
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _uow;

    public UserTitlesOperations(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        _uow = uow;
    }

    public List<UserTitles> GetAllUserTitles()
    {
        try
        {
            List<UserTitles> userTitleList = _uow.UserTitles.GetAll().ToList();
            _uow.Complete();
            return userTitleList;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the `BaseManager` class which gives inheritance to all manager classes.

```
public abstract class BaseManager
{
    private IUnitOfWork _iUow;

    private readonly XaPaDataContext _context;

    public IUnitOfWork IUOW
    {
        get
        {
            if (_iUow == null)
            {
                _iUow = new XaPaUnitOfWork(_context);
            }

            return _iUow;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the manager class:

```
public class UserTitlesManager : BaseManager
{
    private readonly UserTitlesOperations _userTitlesOperations;

    public UserTitlesManager()
    {
        _userTitlesOperations = new UserTitlesOperations(base.IUOW);
    }

    public List<UserTitlesWM> GetAllUserTitles()
    {
        try
        {
            return UserTitlesMapping.MaptoWM(_userTitlesOperations.GetAllUserTitles());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, this is my API Controller:

```
[Route("api/LoginRequest")]
public class TitlesController : BaseController
{
    UserTitlesManager _userTitlesManager;

    public LoginController()
    {
        _userTitlesManager = new UserTitlesManager();
    }

    [Route("RetreiveTitles")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetTitles()
    {
        try
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, _userTitlesManager.GetAllUserTitles());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

By the way `BaseController` is just another API controller which gives inheritance to all other API controllers, and houses a method which is used by all the other controllers.

So, I'm still trying to sharpen my self on this design patterns and would be glad if anyone could show my mistake on `BaseManager` class. As I said, I suppose the problem is caused by that `private readonly XaPaDataContext _context;` line. On the other hand,I can't figure out how to corrrect it  as my operation classes' constructors are asking for `IUnitOfWork`.

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:**

Just realized that I forgot to share my Unit of Work class:

```
public class XaPaUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly XaPaDataContext _context;

    public XaPaUnitOfWork(XaPaDataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        Categories = new CategoriesRepository(_context);
        OrderDetails = new OrderDetailsRepository(_context);
        Orders = new OrdersRepository(_context);
        ProductImages = new ProductImagesRepository(_context);
        Products = new ProductsRepository(_context);
        Users = new UsersRepository(_context);
        UserTitles = new UserTitlesRepository(_context);
        UserTokens = new UserTokensRepository(_context);
    }

    public ICategoriesRepository Categories { get; private set; }
    public IOrderDetailsRepository OrderDetails { get; private set; }
    public IOrdersRepository Orders { get; private set; }
    public IProductImagesRepository ProductImages { get; private set; }
    public IProductsRepository Products { get; private set; }
    public IUsersRepository Users { get; private set; }
    public IUserTitlesRepository UserTitles { get; private set; }
    public IUserTokensRepository UserTokens { get; private set; }

    public int Complete()
    {
        return _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd be nervous of `get { return Context as XaPaDataContext; }` to start with. If `Context` isn't a `XaPaDataContext`, that will return null - so you'll end up with a null reference propagating its way elsewhere, making it really hard to work out what's going on. If you cast instead, then if the type isn't the expected one you'll get a much more specific error at exactly the point where it fails. That may or may not be the problem (you should debug through to work out where things are going wrong) but I suggest you change it anyway.

Comment: Your first problem is you are using a *Repository Pattern* over Entity Framework, You have joyfully, abstracted your self into another layer of maintenance and complexity for little to no gain, Your second problem is you haven't debugged this

Comment: Well, I have debugged of course and system throws the exception after `return Context.Set<T>().ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

After I have changed my BaseManager class as below:

```
public abstract class BaseManager
{
    private IUnitOfWork _iUow;

    public IUnitOfWork IUOW
    {
        get
        {
            if (_iUow == null)
            {
                _iUow = new XaPaUnitOfWork(new XaPaDataContext());
            }

            return _iUow;
        }
    }
}
```

I have achived to receive `HttpStatusCode.OK`

But, honestly, I'm still unsure about the real reason. I make this correction mostly by heart.